# Powershell to list all pages with their layout across the rootweb and all subwebs?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I need to be able to create a report of all existing pages and their page layout.
I have the following powershell script but even using Recursive its only returning me the ones from the root web.

```
filter Get-PublishingPages { 
    $pubweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($_)
    $query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery 
    $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
    $pubweb.GetPublishingPages($query)    
} 
$url="https://xxxxl.com"
get-spweb $url | Get-PublishingPages | select Uri, Title, @{Name='PageLayout';Expression={$_.Layout.ServerRelativeUrl}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
filter Get-PublishingPages {
$pubweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($_)
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery

$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'"
$pubweb.GetPublishingPages($query)
}

$str = "http://yourdomain.com" // your URL
if($str -eq $null )
{
Write-Host “Enter a valid URL”
return
}

$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $str
if($site -eq $null)
{
Write-Host “Enter a valid URL”
return
}

$allweb = $site.Allwebs
foreach($web in $allweb )
{
$web | Get-PublishingPages | select Uri, Title, @{Name=’PageLayout’;Expression={$_.Layout.ServerRelativeUrl}}| Format-List
}
```

Comment: thanks for the script. I had to replace the single quotes around PageLayouts with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a shot in the dark here, but have you tried setting the scope to RecursiveAll instead of just Recursive? My understanding was that Recursive only hit all files in a folder while RecursiveAll gets all subfolders as well.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spviewscope.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: it didnt make any difference :(